Recording different audio streams for one video
#####EDIT#####
An idea was conceived:
First run a local web server where you have js's getUserMedia method to record the video and the audio while noting the same moments' ms relative to a known time (i.e. js's Date.now() method). After recording all audios and the main video, the recording is uploaded to the server, where by cutting out the difference in ms between the audio files and the video everything should be perfect.
However, what if the different devices are not in sync by their internal clocks (e.g. different cell provider)?
Any thoughts?
(I think I will also upload the question to stack overflow... we'll see what they know...)
#####EDIT#####
I am on a mission from my PhD-student-wife, to prepare a simple
software\hardware, simple to use, solution that will allow occupational therapists to record a short video (up to 5 minutes, but usually 2 minutes or less) with 1-4 people ("actors").
She asks that they will be able to do so using their phones (or  of-the-shelf cameras or whatever), while recording each "actor" with their own phones or something.
One option is to find a way to connect multiple Bluetooth microphones to a single computer\phone and simultaneously record all video and audio. The problem is, I don't think a Bluetooth mixer is a "simple enough" solution. Also, using AudioRelay on the phone as server and recording using OBS caused "echoing".
Another option, will be to have a piece of software that can aggregate the main camera audio with audio recorded on the other devices.
I was thinking:

Count 5 4 3 and then quietly count 2 1 while all participants activate their recording devices.
Clapping (with a clapper, or with the hands).
waiting another second or two and then yelling "Action!" and start to "act".
Then using silence recognition to find the clap and sync the streams.

The problem is that I don't know how to handle silence in the video (as part of the happening), and of course, there is the threshold issue (different thresholds to every device), and normalizing volume etc....
Please help.

Videoconference applications like Zoom, Google Meet, etc., have recording facilities that can handle mixing multiple microphones together (one mic from each member of the call), together with a multiple camera inputs and even one main camera input. (the main camera could be one member sharing their screen which shows the view from the main camera)  If you can adapt this to the needs of your wife's recordings, it could be very inexpensive and offers a familiar user interface to all the participants.  Just an idea.

That's a nice take. Thanks (didn't think of this).
So, if I take your suggestion, and "One up" it, I can even  place a server in the room, with AP active, a Jitsi server running, where they all can connect to the one conference (with only one video input and record the conference...).
The problems begin with delays (be it wifi or Internet caused), as one microphone might pickup audio from another participant, causing an "echoing" effect, and there may be a lag between the video and the audio, of different participants (only one video source). again, back to square one with the sync issues.
